# Numerical integration of $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{3+\sin x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods

We know that numerical integration using end points is first order, trapezoid and mid-piont rules second order, and Simpson's rule fourth order. However, with $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{3+\sin x}$, we have the following errors:

```
n   Left point              Right point             Trapezoid               Mid-point               Simpson
1   2.02200572599407E-2     2.02200572599406E-2     2.02200572599406E-2     2.02200572599407E-2     2.02200572599407E-2
2   2.02200572599407E-2     2.02200572599406E-2     2.02200572599406E-2     -2.14466094067260E-2    -7.55772051783715E-3
3   1.80370579205280E-5     1.80370579205280E-5     1.80370579205280E-5     1.80370579205280E-5     1.80370579204725E-5
4   -6.13276073392621E-4    -6.13276073392621E-4    -6.13276073392621E-4    6.12214122685750E-4     2.03717390659608E-4
5   1.56304432175070E-8     1.56304432175070E-8     1.56304432175070E-8     1.56304432175070E-8     1.56304432175070E-8
6   1.80370579205280E-5     1.80370579205280E-5     1.80370579205280E-5     -1.80379781545281E-5    -6.01296612956492E-6
7   1.35448319227294E-11    1.35448319227294E-11    1.35448319227294E-11    1.35449429450318E-11    1.35449429450318E-11
8   -5.30975353407737E-7    -5.30975353463248E-7    -5.30975353407737E-7    5.30974556545161E-7     1.76991253264536E-7
9   1.20459198171829E-14    1.19904086659517E-14    1.20459198171829E-14    1.19904086659517E-14    1.20459198171829E-14
10  1.56304431619958E-8     1.56304431619958E-8     1.56304431619958E-8     -1.56304434395516E-8    -5.21014786869500E-9
```

Simpson is surprised. Why are the end points over-performing? Another interesting fact is that the errors are not converging steadily but rather in an oscillating manner. Is there any explanation for this?

Comment: How do you apply the Simpson rule to 6 function values separating 5 sub-intervals?

Comment: @LutzL I used $S = \frac13(T+2M)$, where $S$ is Simpson, $T$ is trapezoid and $M$ is mid-point.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge's_phenomenon

Comment: The results converge nicely if you separate even $n$ from odd ones. The reason for the fast convergence is the periodicity of the integrand - all formulas converge quicker that any power of $h$. The actual error seems to be $O(e^{-\alpha n})$